# What is the Greatest Mitzvah?

Tags: mitzvah, priorities

What is the greatest Mitzvah a man can do?

Comment: To impart with others any portion of knowledge which one is sure to have acquired about G-d, the Creator of the universe.

Comment: @HodofHod: I prefer the old title, as now it is too similar to the body.

Comment: @DoubleAA I agree, but then, there isn't much to the body in the first place. The general idea is that you should be able to guess the general topic of a question from its title, _before clicking on it_. I couldn't, so I edited. Feel free to rework the body to be more elaborate or whatnot.

Comment: Wikipedia's "Chevra kadisha" page says, "[...] Tending to a meit mitzvah [mitzvah corpse] overrides virtually any other positive commandment (mitzvat aseh) of Torah law." Any truth to this?

Answer (score 5):

V'**Talmud Torah** K'negged Kulom

Comment: מילה ששקולה כנגד כל המצות

Comment: שבת ששקולה כנגד כל המצות

Comment: צדקה ששקולה כנגד כל המצות

Comment: ישיבת ארץ ישראל ששקולה כנגד כל המצות

Comment: ציצית ששקולה כנגד כל המצות

Answer (score 5):

According to [Rebbi Y'huda Hanasi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabbi_Yehuda_Ha-Nasi) [we do not know](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%90%D7%91%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%91_%D7%90).

Comment: However, acc. to Tosfos there, we may know in a vacuum, but the reward for each changes according to the challanges of the moment

Comment: @YDK - Tosfos on Pirkei Avos?

Comment: @AdamMosheh, sorry, Tosfos Yom Tov.